# how do you keep a sticky header from running on a small resolution

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, sticky

I want to have a sticky navbar on all resolutions except mobile resolutions. I want this code to be able to run if people resize the window down to mobile as well. When the page loads, it works just fine, but when I resize the browser, the width variable does not update. Here is the code I am using.

```
var width = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){
    width = $(window).width();
})

if ( width >=768 ) {
    $('.mainNavWrap').sticky({topSpacing:42});
}
```

I added a fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/DR5aX/

Comment: Why don't use css for this with width being 100%

Comment: I dont know what you mean.

Comment: I guess you only need to make the top nav to resize as per your browser window then why don't you simply use `topnav{width:100%}` whose parent is your document. But I am afraid I haven't got your question.

Comment: Ok so I need the header to only be sticky above a certain resolution. Hold on, im going to make a fiddle for this. Give me one second

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/DR5aX/

Answer (score 0):

do like this

```
var width = $(window).width();

$(window).resize(function(){

  width = $(window).width();
if ( width >=768 ) {
    $('.mainNavWrap').sticky({topSpacing:42});
}

})
```

Comment: Ok that works, but it only works after the user resizes. What if the user never resizes? Wouldnt it not work?

edit:
Actually that version does not work on mobile

Comment: Try to add the same code in window.load event too, so that it will fire once after the page got loaded.. and it will also fires when user resizes the browser..